# Сполз рейтинг вопросов и ответов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

Собственно, вот:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: И https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5320/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC

Comment: Проблема именно на МЕТЕ

Comment: @Egor, исправили)

Comment: http://howtocenterincss.com

хехе