# Визуальные дефекты в вопросах на Мете

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

Количество голосов уползло вниз (поправка: об этом уже есть [в другом вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5321/10105)), а верхний луч звёздочки перекрыт чем-то непрозрачным (а об этом нету). На основном сайте проблема не наблюдается.

Скриншот:

---

[image: ужасы нового дизайна! ааааа!]

Comment: Я первый)) А вообще, уже поправили)))

Comment: И точно, поправили! Тогда надо вешать [meta-tag:статус-завершено].