# Дефекты в профиле

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн, профиль-участника, навигация

Текст скрывается за шапкой:

> [image: влияние]

Некорректно отображает маркеры в профиле:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: баян https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5326/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5

Comment: @Alex78191 не дубликат. Там про дефекты в сообщениях. У меня про дефекты в профиле.

Comment: Одна причина этого

Comment: Нечего на мета сидеть, что тут интересного

Comment: @Alex78191 я не против объединения тем. Уже 4 разных автора с разными дефектами стилей

Comment: Частично исправили дефекты. Остался тот, где сообщение за шапку залезает.

Comment: Дефект с блоком "влияние" описан так же на [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349758/3240681).