# Покажите мне дублирование!

Tags: поддержка

При попытке опубликовать вопрос говорится, что он дублирует другой, хотя это не так:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Еще это https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5320/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-meta-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC Это все из-за одного правила CSS

Comment: @Nicolas может надо вешать дополнительно [meta-tag:статус-так-задумано] вместо замены [meta-tag:дефект] на [meta-tag:поддержка]?

Comment: @alexolut Вероятно, вы правы.

Comment: @alexolut, лучше бы ответ кто-то повесил ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy для этого его надо знать. Может Николас знает.